# Using the eventlimitclick on fullcalendario

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

So I integrated a calendar on fullcalendar.io and when there is a lot of events on a single day there a link saying '+2 more' or whatever the amount is. The problem I am having is that whenever i click this link the window that shows all events appears at the bottom of the screen and I can barely see it. This is not convenient. Is there a way I can display it on the middle of the screen or right next to the day I clicked on.
Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Can you make [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vzxLyfua/) for it?

Comment: which version are you using? are you showing events in agendaDay view if user clicked "+2 more'. ?